# Getting Bad_alloc thrown when running this code

Tags: c++

I am getting a bad_alloc thrown when I run the executable generated from this code. I do not know why it's being thrown (I can guess it's coming from that new statement)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void gen_numbers(long int numbers[], long int how_many)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < how_many; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
}

bool is_prime(long int n)
{
    if(n < 2) 
        return false;
    for(int i=2; i<=sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int count_prime_serial(long int numbers[], long int how_many)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<how_many; i++)
    {
        if(is_prime(numbers[i]))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    long int n = 1000000000;
    long int* numbers = new long int[n];
    gen_numbers(numbers, n);
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int count = count_prime_serial(numbers, n);
    
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double compute_time = chrono::duration<double>(end - start).count();
    cout<<"Total number of primes = "<<count<<endl;
    cout<<"Total computation time = "<<compute_time<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any solution to stop getting this error during runtime?

I've tried compiling and running the exact same code on another machine and it ran just fine, this is why I am confused.

Comment: An array of `1000000000` `long int`'s is going to need 4GB (or 8GB on 64 bit wide long systems) of contiguous space in ram.  Does your system have that available?

Comment: For one, you don't need `long int` to represent what is effectively a *flag* if the purpose of this is ultimately a SoE.

Comment: The only value you're storing in `numbers` is each index value, so it's actually pointless to allocate any memory for it at all. Just do `is_prime(i)` instead of `is_prime(numbers[i])`. Also, `i` should be a `long int`

Comment: The code was given to me from an instructor and is meant for a baseline sequential solution to be parallelized. He did warn me it was hastily put together and didn't follow best practices. Thanks a lot for the help guys! After looking at it again, I really don't need any special allocation to get his sequential solution to work.

Comment: Tactical note: This looks like a good place to employ [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). It'll save you a huge amount of space.

Comment: If you really want prime hunting to zip along, forget about threads. [Use a sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_of_primes).